# Cancelling of UILOcalNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using UILocalNotifications in my app.Now my requirement is the local notification should be cancelled after it’s scheduled.

Here my Code…

```
-(void)LocalNotificationMethod{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate =  self.selectedDate;
    NSLog(@" self.selectedDate %@", self.selectedDate);
    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    NSLog(@"itemDate %@",itemDate);
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
      NSLog(@"itemDate %@", localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [_titleTextFieldObj text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSLog(@" localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber ++ %ld", (long)localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber );



    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[_titleTextFieldObj text] forKey:@"someKey"];

    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"notif %@",notificationArray);


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


   }

**In Appdelegate.m i wrote the code like…**

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
           if (notification) {
            NSLog(@"notify %@",notification);
            NSString *custom=[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"];
             NSLog(@"custom %@",custom);
             NSString *newString = [custom stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

             NSLog(@"newString %@",newString);

            NSLog(@"custmky%@",notification.description);
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:newString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            alert.delegate=self;
            [alert show];


        }
        //UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSString *notificationId = @"id_to_cancel";
        //UILocalNotification *notification = nil;
        for(UILocalNotification *notify in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
        {
            if([[notify.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"] isEqualToString:notificationId ])
            {
                notification = notify;
                break;
            }
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];


    }
```

but it is not going into the loop …

I am new to this concept.Can anyone please help me to resolve this….
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array?

Comment: Yes.I am getting the scheduled local notifications in console also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cancel a scheduled notification based on receiving another notification, if it is the case you need to put the loop before showing the Alert else your loop will never be executed. or in case you need to cancel/or not notification based button that will be taped in your AlertView you can put that code in your alertView delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex==0) {

        for(UILocalNotification *notify in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]){

            if([[notify.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"] isEqualToString:@"someValue"]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notify];
                break;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: I worte the code like this in alertView delegate method.Is it right or not?

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
         UILocalNotification *notification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        for(UILocalNotification *notify in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
        {
           
            if([[notify.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"] isEqualToString:custom ])
            {
                notification = notify;
                break;
            }
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

Comment: I updated the code, It will cancel a scheduled notification based on receiving another notification. the notification received will no more be available in scheduledLocalNotifications array

Answer (score 0):

By Default all `UILocalNotification` is `OneTime` so it cancel automatically after its `fireDate`

And looks like you are trying to get same `UILocalNotification`.

Please try putting same code at different place you will get all your `Scheduled Notifications` Or try to get all `Scheduled Notifications` before `fireDate`.

Comment: I am getting the scheduled notifications in an array.

Comment: Hi 
May be looks like little bit issue in Under Standing
Lets clear out

Suppose you are settled out 5 `LocalNotification` Namely `1,2,3,4,5`

Your first (1)`LocalNotification` get fired and you got that in `didReceiveLocalNotification` Method.

Now if you will print `Scheduled Notifications` you will get only `2,3,4,5` as `1` is already fired.

May be you are trying to access `UILocalNotification 1`